# Sending multiple http post requests in loop

Tags: http, post, vbscript

How can I do request looping in request header?
I have whole day transaction stored in my database.
My server will send all this value to another server to update payment status.

My VBScript code.

```
 do while not abc.eof sUrl = "https:/abc.com"

            sRequest = "ID="&escape(a)&"&CODE="&escape(b)&"&NAME="&(strEncrypted)


            HTTPPost sUrl, sRequest         Function HTTPPost(sUrl, sRequest)
              Set oHTTP=Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
              oHTTP.setOption 2, 13056
              oHTTP.open "POST", sUrl,false
              oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
              oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
              oHTTP.send sRequest
              HTTPPost = oHTTP.responseText
             End Function    abc.movenext      loop
```

Comment: What you tried and whay is the error?

Comment: when i used this code without looping process there is no error..but when i put <do while not> above the code, there will be SYNTAX ERROR ..

Comment: Show the error and code to loop

Comment: i do not know is it correct or not my code above...i just put <do while not abc.eof > then close with <abc.movenext> and <loop>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcion (...) must be outside the Do While (...)